# How to set real time clock in Raspberry PI instead of setting fake clock

Tags: raspbian, system-clock

I would like to know how to set Real Time Clock instead of Fake Clock in Raspberry PI.

Hope you guys could help me out with it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raspberry Pi doesn't have a real time clock. You can easily add a cheap ($2) one using I2C (eg DS1307). Setting/Reading the time can then be done using the I2C library of your favourite language.

Searching the web for `rasberry pi ds1307` turns up lots of help

Comment: I always forget the Pi has no realtime clock because it is connected either wirelessly or via ethernet to the internet and the built in NTP client sets the clock. You could run your own NTP server on an internal network if connecting to the internet is not an option.