# Make sure that RPi 400 clock is always synced

Tags: timekeeping, pi-400

**tl;dr** *Exactly what steps must a newbie like me undertake to configure RPi 400 in the way that it obtains current time from some official NTP server every time it boots up?*

---

I am just trying my first steps with RPi 400, but I hit the wall with not being able to setup my Pi's clock. Neither manually nor through NTP.

My first attempt was to try to do this purely manually, but opening calendar and clicking througs different days, months, years brings no effect. System clock is all the time set to December 26th, 2022.

My next attempt was to use [*timedatectl*](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-time-on-raspberry-pi#:%7E:text=Set%20time%20on%20a%20Raspberry%20Pi%20via%20timedatectl%20(systemd)%20or%20date%20command). Executing just:

```
sudo timedatectl
```

told me that my timezone is correct and that my NTP sync is on.

This should be enough per [this comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19683/how-to-set-real-time-clock-in-raspberry-pi-instead-of-setting-fake-clock#comment26130_19684), where rob says that when my Pi "is connected either wirelessly or via ethernet to the internet and the built in NTP client sets the clock". This turns out to be untrue in my case. I have Internet connection and I still have clock behind.

I dig through internet and found a suggestion to execute:

```
sudo apt install ntp
```

Did so and all that I achieved was... that *timedatectl* started to claim that my NTP sync is inactive. And no way to make it active again, because executing:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

with or without rebooting Pi brings no effect.

Comment: `I still have clock behind` - how far behind, and what is `datetimectl`, perhaps it's a malicious frontend to `timedatectl`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JaromandaX Really sorry, I was writing from my memory and mixed it up. Of course, I am talking about `timedatectl`. Fixed in the question. How far? I'd say that around **9 months**. Started my RPi two days ago (September 13th, 2023) and found it showing December 22nd, 2022. This date is around the time I have purchased this device, as it has around 9 months of living in a box.

Comment: @Milliways I know that this will sound dumb, but... I don't know. This is my first RPi 400 (spent some time with RPi 3B, but without Desktop) and I have zero experience with it. I have just unboxed it and run for the first time. All I know that it has _Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop_ on board. It is either the one that was already on RPi 400 (if it ships with OS preinstalled) or it was installed by the person who has sold it to me (I've got it from a second-hand; not from the official channel, though it was said to be new). I don't pretty much know how to check the version, sorry.

Comment: `lsb_release -irdc` will tell you what OS but frankly if you have an OS which has been (mis)configured by someone else you would be better to perform a fresh installation (as suggested by Joan) - which works out of the box and sets the correct time. If you understand the OS it is possible to fix but probably faster (and more reliable) to start from fresh.

Comment: @Milliways Probably all of you are correct! :(

Answer (score 3):

1. Download and flash any Linux distribution from the Raspberry Pi org site.
2. Boot
3. Stop fiddling (optional)

Comment: Shouldn't the above happen / be done by someone who prepared system for my RPi 400? Does this mean that I have purchased my RPi 400 with some non-original Raspbian? I did nothing. Just unboxed my RPi 400, powered it up only to learn that the clock is way off and no automatic time sync is in place when I connect it to some Wi-Fi.

Comment: Most people flash their own sd cards with Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop. What happens if you navigate to google.com in Chromium?

Comment: @CoderMike Visiting google.com and all other websites that I have tried says pretty much the same: "Sorry, your clock it to far behind to work our certificates out correctly".

Comment: The google website should ask you to sync time now - what happens if you do that?

Comment: I cannot sync time automatically, because I don't know how to force RPi to reach out for some NTP server. I didn't tried to set the time manually (with `date` function) so far.